# How to parse this Json using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am getting only first id JSON object data here is my Interface class :

```
@POST("webservices.php?view=get_products")
Call<MultipleProductList> sendMultipleProducts();
```

and my response class i created my response class by online json parsing website 
 http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ i am getting only first json object data please try to solve this :

```
{
"success": "true",
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "27",
        "post_title": "Beanie",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "beanie",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/beanie.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "20",
        "sale_price": "18",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "18"
    },
    {
        "ID": "28",
        "post_title": "Belt",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "belt",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/belt.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "65",
        "sale_price": "55",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "55"
    },
    {
        "ID": "29",
        "post_title": "Cap",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "cap",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cap.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "18",
        "sale_price": "16",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "16"
    },
    {
        "ID": "30",
        "post_title": "Sunglasses",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "sunglasses",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sunglasses.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "90",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "90"
    },
    {
        "ID": "31",
        "post_title": "Hoodie with Logo",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "hoodie-with-logo",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hoodie-with-logo.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "45",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "45"
    },
    {
        "ID": "32",
        "post_title": "Hoodie with Pocket",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "hoodie-with-pocket",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hoodie-with-pocket.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "45",
        "sale_price": "35",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "price": "35",
        "stock_status": "instock"
    },
    {
        "ID": "33",
        "post_title": "Hoodie with Zipper",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "hoodie-with-zipper",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hoodie-with-zipper.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "45",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "45"
    },
    {
        "ID": "34",
        "post_title": "Hoodie",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "hoodie",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hoodie.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "45",
        "sale_price": "42",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "42"
    },
    {
        "ID": "35",
        "post_title": "Long Sleeve Tee",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "long-sleeve-tee",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/long-sleeve-tee.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "25",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "25"
    },
    {
        "ID": "36",
        "post_title": "Polo",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "polo",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/polo.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "20",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "20"
    },
    {
        "ID": "37",
        "post_title": "Tshirt",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "tshirt",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/tshirt.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "18",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "18"
    },
    {
        "ID": "38",
        "post_title": "Vneck Tshirt",
        "post_type": "product",
        "post_content": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "post_name": "vneck-tee",
        "image": "http://localhost/mobileappstore/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/vneck-tee.jpg",
        "average_rating": "0",
        "sku": "",
        "regular_price": "18",
        "sale_price": "",
        "total_sales": "0",
        "stock_status": "instock",
        "price": "18"
    }
],
"msg": "product list"
```

}

I am getting first id response and my retrofit class is :

```
 public void setData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .build();

    Apiinterface apiinterface = retrofit.create(Apiinterface.class);
    Call<MultipleProductList> call = apiinterface.sendMultipleProducts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MultipleProductList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MultipleProductList> call, Response<MultipleProductList> response) {
            response.body();

            String success = response.body().getSuccess();
            String message = response.body().getMsg();
            Log.e("success", success);
            Log.e("msg", message);

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseData = response.body().toString();
                Log.e("here", "onResponse: " + responseData);

                MultipleProductList multipleProductList = response.body();
                multipleProductList.getData();


                List<DataProduct> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayList = multipleProductList.getData();
                arrayList.size();

                String id = arrayList.get(0).getID();
                String post_type = arrayList.get(0).getPostType();
                String regularPrice = arrayList.get(0).getRegularPrice();
                String sale_price = arrayList.get(0).getSalePrice();
                String post_content = arrayList.get(0).getPostContent();
                String post_status = arrayList.get(0).getPostStatus();
                String post_name = arrayList.get(0).getPostName();
                String average_rating = arrayList.get(0).getAverageRating();
                String sku = arrayList.get(0).getSku();
                String post_title = arrayList.get(0).getPostTitle();
                String total_sales = arrayList.get(0).getTotalSales();
                String stock_status = arrayList.get(0).getStockStatus();
                String price = arrayList.get(0).getPrice();

                String img = arrayList.get(0).getImage();

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(img).fit().into(img_saree);

             /*   Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(img)
                        .into(img_saree);*/
                Log.e("id", id);
                Log.e("regularPrice", regularPrice);
                Log.e("sale_price", sale_price);
                Log.e("image_pic", img);
                Log.e("post_content", post_content);
                Log.e("post_status", post_status);
                Log.e("post_name", post_name);
                Log.e("average_rating", average_rating);
                Log.e("sku", sku);
                Log.e("post_title", post_title);
                Log.e("total_sales", total_sales);
                Log.e("stock_status", stock_status);
                Log.e("price", price);
                Log.e("post_type", post_type);

                Gson gson = new Gson();



            } else {
                Log.i("debug", "onResponse: GA BERHASIL");
            }
        }
```

Comment: *i am getting only first json object data*  ...`arrayList.get(0)` <= how? how  you only getting only first object ... are you familiar with such basic programming term like **iteration**?

Comment: i am getting ID = 27 data not another object below please tell me how to change in POJO class to get another JSON object data .

Comment: `arrayList.get(0)` <= change 0 to 1 ...and ... magic ... you will get second item ... you can also learn how to iterate a List

Answer (score 0):

try this one using volley

```
    private void JSON_HTTP_CALL(String url)
{



    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_pro");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {

                    JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name,email,gender,mobileno,city,country;

                    String base_url = getString(R.string.url);
                    String img_path = base_url+jsonObject1.getString("emp_image");

                    jsonObject1.getString("id");
                    name=jsonObject1.getString("name");
                    email=jsonObject1.getString("email");



                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(img_path).into(User_pic);
                    User_name.setText(name);
                    User_email.setText(email);



                }


            }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```